# C# - Windows Service EventMonitor function with parameters

Tags: c#, service, smartcard

I'm using PCSC library for SmartCard Readers events detection and trying to use it in Windows service.
Readers search function:

```
 private void CheckPresentReaders()
    {
        using (var context = new SCardContext())
        {
            context.Establish(SCardScope.System);
            PresentCardReaders = context.GetReaders();
        }
    }
```

SmartCard removed function:

```
private void SCardRemoved(object sender, CardStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteToLog("Locking machine. SmartCard was removed.");
       // LockWorkStation();
    }
```

Monitor creation:

```
 CheckPresentReaders();
        if (PresentCardReaders.Length != 0)
        {
            SCardMonitor monitor = new SCardMonitor(ContextFactory.Instance, SCardScope.System);
            monitor.CardRemoved += new CardRemovedEvent(SCardRemoved);
            foreach (string reader in PresentCardReaders)
                monitor.Start(reader);
        }
```

WriteToLog function is a simple Log Entry creation function.

When it is compiled - service starting and then stopping immediately.
I have two suspects - not delegated WriteToLog and/or SCardRemoved, which requires two parameters -

> (object sender, CardStatusEventArgs e)
>   Those are required by library.

Can this be a problem? Any other suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233593/pcsc-invalidcontextexception-when-running-as-a-windows-service and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2011/05/19/scardestablishcontext-fails-with-scard_e_no_service-error/ already? What kind of exception does it throw? If it crashes, the eventlog should contain the stacktrace+exception message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented it properly into Topshelf Service and it does work.

https://github.com/35359595/SmartCardMonitorService